# no class def found

Tags: java, classpath, noclassdeffounderror

I want to run a  .bat file using c#.
for this I set the class path of the JDK1.6 manually.but it is giving an error

```
"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xalan/xslt/process"
```

how this can be removed.

Comment: You need to add to classpath this library: http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/

Answer (score 3):

This is a third party library dependency that must be added to the classpath.  Find the JAR file for this and reference it in your java command.

```
java -cp [CLASSPATH]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `xalan.jar` and its dependencies

http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/downloads.html